# How to get python-dbus in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, dbus

I need to use dbus in my python project, but when i use NuGet to find it, it only lists dbus sharp. Can I use dbus-sharp in python?

Thanks for your response

Comment: Typing 'dbus in python' into google yields this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbus-python. (You want to use `pip` to manage python packages).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the link. But how do I make MS Visual studio community 2015 use the dbus file? In other words - how do I add it as an extension?

Comment: I believe that's already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185827/can-pip-be-used-with-python-tools-in-visual-studio