# import psutil ImportError: No module named psutil

Tags: python, psutil

I am working on MacOS BigSur/Version 11.5.2/ Python 3.9.5.

So i keep getting this import mistake when i try to run my python code:

*import subprocess

import psutil

import schedule

import time

import csv

import sys

import httpx

import asyncio

import json

csv_headers = ["company_id", "dep_id", "host_id", "cpu_count", "cpu_load", "ram_total",
"ram_used", "diskspace_total", "diskspace_used", "diskspace_free", "operations_read",
"operations_write", "timeresponse_min_ms", "timeresponse_avg_ms", "timeresponse_max_ms"]

def get_statistics_windows():

```
statistics = {}

statistics['company_id'] = "comp301"

statistics['dep_id'] = "dep301"

statistics['host_id'] = "host301"
# Get Physical and Logical CPU Count
physical_and_logical_cpu_count = psutil.cpu_count()
statistics['cpu_count'] = physical_and_logical_cpu_count
# Get CPU load in percentage (system wide)
statistics['cpu_load'] = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
# Memory usage
statistics['ram_total'] = round(psutil.virtual_memory().total / 1024 ** 3, 2)
statistics['ram_used'] = round(psutil.virtual_memory().used / 1024 ** 3, 2)
#Disk Usage
statistics['diskspace_total'] = round(psutil.disk_usage('/').total / 1024 ** 3, 2)
statistics['diskspace_used'] = round(psutil.disk_usage('/').used / 1024 ** 3, 2)
statistics['diskspace_free'] = round(psutil.disk_usage('/').free / 1024 ** 3, 2)
statistics['operations_read'] = psutil.disk_io_counters().read_count # read bytes
statistics['operations_write'] = psutil.disk_io_counters().write_count # written bytes
# Network latency
ping_result = subprocess.run(['ping', '-i 5', '-c 5', 'google.com'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode(
    'utf-8').split('\n')
min_response_time, max_response_time, avg_response_time = ping_result[0].split('=')[-1], ping_result[1].split('=')[-1], ping_result[2].split('=')[-1]
statistics['timeresponse_min_ms'] = min_response_time.replace('ms', '').strip()
statistics['timeresponse_avg_ms'] = avg_response_time.replace('ms', '').strip()
statistics['timeresponse_max_ms'] = max_response_time.replace('ms', '').strip()
return statistics*
```

There is 100% no mistake in the code because i was asked to test it, so it works on other machines.
I tried to do

pip install psutil

and got - "Successfully installed psutil-5.8.0" response but in my Visual Studio i still keep getting this error.

I also used a command  sudo pip install --upgrade psutil which successfully update the package but still doesnt seem to work in my Visual Studio

Does anybody know how to make my Visual Studio see this package, so my code could run?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Format code properly

Comment: perhaps visual studio uses different python version

Comment: *There is 100% no mistake in the code*. That assumption always leads to fun adventures. On a serious note, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185827/can-pip-be-used-with-python-tools-in-visual-studio