# No module named "pygame" after using pip

Tags: python, pip, pygame, modulenotfounderror

I am a beginner and I want to work with the pygame module. I have already used pip install to install pygame and it says so on my command prompt. On my command prompt it says:

Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\35192\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (2.1.2)

However, when I try to import pygame in vscode, the module won't import and it says: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the error trace.

Comment: You probably have more than one version of python installed, and `pip` is using a different one than vscode is. Try installing it with `python -m pip install pygame`. If the version of python on your path is the same one vscode uses, that will solve it.

Comment: @baileythegreen I do have more than one version of python installed. I have tried that command and I still get the same error unfortunately :(. How can I run the same version of python everywhere?

Comment: *Everywhere* is probably not a question I can answer, as I don't know your computer setup. However, you can run `which python` from the command line, and that will tell you where the copy it's running is located. I assume vscode has a way to run shell commands inside it, so you can do the same there, or look in the settings (I don't know where) to see where it is getting python from. Changing the location in vscode to what you get from the command line would do it—*but there are reasons why that might be a bad idea*, like if one is python2 and the other python3, and you need it like that.

Comment: @AntónioRebelo, Maybe see if vscode has a way to install packages; or, if you can run shell commands within it, run `python -m pip install pygame` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. I basically just used Ctrl+Shift+P to open up the command palette. From there, I opened "Python: Select interpreter" and then I just changed the python interpreter to be the global one (which I assume is the one used by the command prompt)

Answer (score 0):

As seen here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185827/can-pip-be-used-with-python-tools-in-visual-studio#:~:text=Go%20to%20Tools%20-%3E%20Python%20Tools%20-%3E%20Python,enter%20your%20module%20and%20double%20click%20to%20install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185827/can-pip-be-used-with-python-tools-in-visual-studio#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Tools%20-%3E%20Python%20Tools%20-%3E%20Python,enter%20your%20module%20and%20double%20click%20to%20install).

You have to go to `Tools` -> `Python Tools` -> `Python Environments` in vs code. Then click on your python installation, then pip, and install pygame.

Or you can find where your vs code python installation is, and run this: `"directory to vs code python.exe" -m pip install pygame`

If you would like to use one python installation everywhere, you can change your vs code interpreter/environment to the python you already have installed on your system. As seen here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python

Comment: I can't find 'tools', where is it?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean, could you explain further please (the last edit)

Comment: For example, if your python.exe file for vs code (python interpreter/app) is in: C:\Program Files\Python310. Load up a terminal in this directory (Use CD command for windows), and then do: python.exe -m pip install pygame. If your interpreter has a different name then change python.exe to your interpreters file name. Edit: You should take a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W--_EOzdTHk

Comment: Are you on windows? What is your OS?

Comment: I am on windows. How do I know which installation is in my vs code?